# Avoiding "Exceeded maximum execution time" in Google Sheet for File Listing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to archive some research documents submitted. We currently have over 100k in the library. I tried using this script https://gist.github.com/abubelinha/c797c4b9c5f0da28e351de20ab7f433c and it works awesomely until you get the "Exceeded maximum execution time"

Can anyone advise how I can work around this? We're trying to build the catalogue you see so harvesting a full list would be awesome.

Comment: Google App Script has quotas that no one can do much about except try to code better.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas.  I notice the github library does a lot of sheet.appendRow().  That's probably what's causing the time issue.

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot test your situation, in your situation, is this library useful? https://github.com/tanaikech/FilesApp

Answer (score 0):

See here for an updated library: https://gist.github.com/mesgarpour/07317e81e9ee2b3f1699

Comment: Checked this. Still getting the same error.